# How do I fully relocate my user's home directory to another disk?

Tags: user-account, migration

I installed Lion on a new disk today and let the migration assistant move users, applications and stuff from my internal disk to the SSD connected via FW800. So far everything works great.

Because I have a pretty large photos and audio library, I want to leave my user's home directory on the old Volume and have OS and Applications on the other disk.

To achieve this I opened up `Terminal.app`, sudo'd and entered the following command:

```
cd /Users
mv mwidmann mwidmann_
ln -s /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/mwidmann .
chown -R mwidmann:mwidmann mwidmann
```

So far so good.

In finder the home folder was replaced with mwidmann_, but I removed that item from the sidebar and added the new one instead. Same goes for documents, downloads, pictures, videos, music. Other items I added there, worked like before.

Why I feel that I'm missing something is because the nice sidebar and dock icons for these "special" folders aren't showing up.

There must be an additional thing that tells Lion that **THIS** is my home folder and it is in `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/mwidmann` and nowhere else.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also go System Preferences > Users & Group, right click on your username, click Advanced Options, and set the path of your Home directory. I also feel it's a more "robust" solution, because it's "endorsed" by Apple.

Comment: Cool! I wasn't able to find this menu as it only shows when the lock is unlocked and I _always_ forget about it.

Comment: Does this copy all files/folders in the existing directory to the new location? If not, What's the likeliness of moving the home directory screwing something up on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution!

I had to restart the computer and re-set the shortcuts and now it's working like I want it to. All the icons are showing up like I wanted.

So it really seems to be enough to just move the folder, set a link, set the correct permissions and that's it.