# Splitting user and system across multiple volumes

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, mount

I'm migrating from a large HDD (1.25TB DIY Fusion Drive) to a pair of SSDs (256GB + 1TB). I want the 256GB one to mount as /, and the 1TB one to mount as /Users. In previous versions of OSX, you could just edit /etc/fstab like in any other UNIX, but in Tiger they removed that in favor of NetInfo Manager. But now NetInfo Manager is gone.  Is there any way to arbitrarily and UNIXily set mount points for different volumes?

Or, since my real end goal is to put my user files on a different volume than the boot volume, is there a way to set a user to [put their home directory on another volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20043/how-do-i-fully-relocate-my-users-home-directory-to-another-disk) *before* running Migration Assistant to restore their files? I definitely do not have enough space to restore everything to the system disk, and in the past, Migration Assistant hasn't provided any means of configuring a user before restoring it (or even restoring a user's files from another installation into an existing user on a new installation).

Or, could I restore everything to the 1TB SSD, and then somehow transfer the OS and applications to the 256GB SSD while leaving the user files behind on the larger volume?

Comment: And, before anyone just recommends setting up a unified CoreStorage volume, the reason I'm going to a pair of separate SSDs is I've found Fusion Drive to be incredibly unreliable and corruption-prone.

Comment: So, it looks like OSX Mavericks isn't making a complete system backup via Time Machine for some reason, so for now I'm just backing up my userdir specifically via rsync and will just install a fresh system and rsync my user files over. It'd still be nice to know the Right Way to put my user files on a separate drive, though.